Anaconda/Miniconda won't work - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
This last month I was happily working with the Anaconda Navigator and Pycharm. However, after I wanted to install a new virtual environment for the NoW Benchmark evaluation I received the following error after re-opening my Anaconda Prompt:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-scripts.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

I saw in many discussions that a cause could be that multiple versions of python exist on the device, which was indeed the case. I therefore removed Anaconda Navigator, Pycharm, and anything I could find regarding conda and virtual environments. Nevertheless, after performing a fresh install of Anaconda Navigator, the program does not want to open, and the Anaconda Prompt provides the same error.
After again uninstalling the Anaconda Navigator, I tried installing Miniconda instead, but the same error is given. Some discussions mentioned to remove PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME from the home and user variables, but I don't have them. Also, I added the following to the system path:
C:\Users\username\miniconda3
C:\Users\username\miniconda3\Scripts

where I filled my actual username, but I'm not showing it here as it's my name.
I also checked whether another python.exe exists in the system (with where python in cmd) and found two:
C:\Users\username\miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

That is everything I tried or checked, and still the error occurs. Does any of you know how to fix it? I could really use your help!
EDIT: The error originated from installing miniconda only to the current user. Selecting the box to install it for all users solved the issue.
